# gpg not asking for a passphrase in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, gnupg

I have attempted to write a bash script to decrypt a gpg file and output the result (so I can copy the password into an application). Afterwards it wipes the file.

Outside of a bash script the passphrase is successfully prompted for.

However, when I run the bash script it jumps straight to outputing the file contents without prompting for the passphrase?

The script is below.

I am just starting out with scripting - please can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

thanks

```
1 ###################################
2 # securely decrypt password file and delete
3 ###################################
4 #secure wipe gpgout directory
5 wipe -rfi ~/programs/utils/scripts/gpg/gpgout/*
6 #decrypt p1.gpg to file p1.txt
7 gpg -o ~/programs/utils/scripts/gpg/gpgout/p1.txt -d ~/programs/utils/scripts/gpg/p1.gpg
8 #clear cached password
9 echo RELOADAGENT | gpg-connect-agent
10 #print p1.txt password to the terminal
11 cat p1.txt
12 #secure wipe gpgout directory again to remove p1.txt
13 wipe -rfi ~/programs/utils/scripts/gpg/gpgout/*
14 #silence bash output
15 #https://www.baeldung.com/linux/silencing-bash-output
16 command > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: To be sure, you're asking why your bash script doesn't query for the passphrase and still decrypts the p1.gpg file without trouble ?

Comment: exactly - I want the script to prompt for the passphrase - not sure if I need to explicitly tell it to do this within the bash script? gpg -o ~/programs/utils/scripts/gpg/gpgout/p1.txt -d ~/programs/utils/scripts/gpg/p1.gpg

Comment: works OK outside of the script and prompts for the passphrase. Inside the script it doesnt and just gives me the decrypted result? thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using  gpg-agent which store keys and passphrase.
To prevent gpg-agent to provide keys/passphrase to gpg, you should force the gpg-agent reload before the gpg call :

```sh
###################################
# securely decrypt password file and delete
###################################
#secure wipe gpgout directory
wipe -rfi ~/programs/utils/scripts/gpg/gpgout/*
#decrypt p1.gpg to file p1.txt
#clear cached password
echo RELOADAGENT | gpg-connect-agent
gpg -o ~/programs/utils/scripts/gpg/gpgout/p1.txt -d ~/programs/utils/scripts/gpg/p1.gpg
#clear cached password
echo RELOADAGENT | gpg-connect-agent
#print p1.txt password to the terminal
cat p1.txt
#secure wipe gpgout directory again to remove p1.txt
wipe -rfi ~/programs/utils/scripts/gpg/gpgout/*
#silence bash output
#https://www.baeldung.com/linux/silencing-bash-output
command > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
```

I'll suggest you also a better way (no subshell) to deal with gpg-connect-agent :

```
gpg-connect-agent reloadagent /bye
```

instead of

```
echo RELOADAGENT | gpg-connect-agent
```